# Binding ViewModel  to ContentControl as its DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to change UserControls on button clicks (I'm not going to complicate here, so I'll only mention important parts). So idea was to bind ViewModels of those UserControls to ContentControl, and than associate them Views using DataTemplates.
Here's the code:

```
<Window x:Class="Project.MainWindow">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type UserControl:ViewUserControlViewModel}" >
        <UserControl:ViewUserControl/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type UserControl:EditUserControlViewModel}" >
        <UserControl:EditUserControl/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding UserControlViewModel}" />
    <Button Content="View" Click="ChangeToView()"/>
    <Button Content="Edit" Click="ChangeToEdit()"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    public DependencyObject UserControlViewModel
    {
        get { return (DependencyObject)GetValue(UserControlViewModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UserControlViewModelProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UserControlViewModelProperty = 
           DependencyProperty.Register("UserControlViewModel", typeof(DependencyObject), typeof(MainWindowViewModel), new PropertyMetadata());

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        UserControlViewModel = new EditUserControlViewModel();
    }
}
```

But theres a problem. When I start project, I only see buttons but not any UserControls. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is this a typo? You Register userControlViewModel but bind to UserControlViewModel.

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. I corrected it now :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If your `Window.DataContext` is properly set to `MainWindowViewModel` this should do the job

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding UserControlViewModel}" />
```

Comment: Yeah, the main issue here is binding the DataContext of the ContentControl instead of the Content. The DataContext doesn't control what the content control will display.

Comment: You are a lifesaver.

Comment: You saved my day

Comment: How is this supposed to work ? A ContentControl should hold a View, not a ViewModel, correct ?

Comment: @csstudent1418 A ContentControl can hold any type of common language runtime object. Please see [remarks of ContentControl Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol?view=net-5.0#remarks)

Comment: I totally understand, of course it works techinically. But why would you want to display a whole *ViewModel*, isn't that just a humongous string that noone wants to see?

Or is there some magical Framework at work here that automatically resolves a corresponding View from the given ViewModel?

Comment: @csstudent1418 That's right. You wouldn't display a ViewModel directly. But DataTemplates link the data (such as ViewModels) to specific views, just like in the sample code of the OP. Then you only need to change the ViewModel and the view changes accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

When doing mvvm your viewmodel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged and not inherit from DependencyObject.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private object _currentWorkspace; //instead of object type you can use a base class or interface
   public object CurrentWorkspace
   {
      get { return this._currentWorkspace; }
      set { this._currentWorkspace = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentWorkspace"); }
   }


   public MainWindowViewModel()
   {
      CurrentWorkspace= new EditUserControlViewModel();
   }

   //todo: to switch the workspace, create DelegeCommand/RelayCommand and set the CurrentWorkspace
   //if you don't know about these commands let me know and i post it

   public ICommand SwitchToViewCommand {get{...}}
   public ICommand SwitchToEditCommand {get{...}}
}
```

xaml: you should set the Content Property to your CurrentWorkspace.

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding UserControlViewModel}" />
<Button Content="View" Comamnd="{Binding SwitchToViewCommand}"/>
<Button Content="Edit" Comamnd="{Binding SwitchToEditCommand}"/>
```

! Don't forget to set the DataContext for your window to your MainWindowViewModel instance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should post the code of your UserControl since (in your code snippet above) it's  responsible for displaying some data.

Second you are not binding anything in your code.

Third your implementation of the ViewModel is wrong. You don't need to subclass a DependencyObject but instead implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in order to establish a ViewModel that is capable of notifying your View.

Fourth I don't know what you are doing with

```
<ContentControl DataContext="{Binding UserControlViewModel}" />
```

maybe you can explain further ?

Fifth when implementing the MVVM patterm (what you currently not do) you should avoid using events like the click event and instead use Commands.

(I know that's not a real answer yet, but I don't wanted to write in comment syntax)

Comment: 1) UserControl code is irrelevant. There are 2 UserControls and both have only one element, Label (ones Content is "View" other ones "Edit")
2) see 4)
3) Where do you see DependencyObject *subclass*? It's a DependencyProperty.
4) It's ContentControl with DateContext that binds to UserControlViewModel DependencyProperty in Project.MainWindow ViewModel