# How can I bind to the design instance of the data context

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I do a binding like this?

```
<local:MySubView d:DataContext="{Binding MyParentView.(d:DesignProperties.DataContext)}"/>
```

I see MySubView doesn't get the DataContext of MyParentView automatically. The syntax above gives the DataContext is unknown.

The MySubView is used as DataTemplate inside MyParentUserControl.Resources. Both user controls should have the same view model. When I create a new instance like I do in MyParentView it is working:

```
<local:MySubView d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MyParentView, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"/>
```

But how can I bind to the same instance?

Comment: Have you tried creating a `StaticResource` and using that in both places?

Comment: Thank you. Yes but static resources are not accessible from MyParentView data context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570754/binding-viewmodel-to-contentcontrol-as-its-datacontext) was the answer. I had the same scenario. The binding was missing on an other place:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource MyContentControlStyle}" >
```